# FillPie() in OnPaint caussing an error after minimizinig

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I've encountered a problem with handling OnPaint event. I have a custom class:

```
namespace WinFormsConsumer
{
    public class Cookie
    {
        public Point Point{get; set;}
        public Color Color { get; set; }
        public int Angle { get; set; }

        public Cookie(Point point, Color color, int angle)
        {
            Point = point;
            Color = color;
            Angle = angle;
        }
    }
}
```

I also defined helper method (taken from class PaintService taken from WebService):

```
public Nullable<Point> StartDraw(int startX, int startY, int width, int height)
        {
            try
            {
                int X = rnd.Next(startX, width);
                int Y = rnd.Next(startY + height);
                return (new Point(X, Y));
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Later on, I've created a form. In it I have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
PaintService ps = new PaintService();

private List<Cookie> list = new List<Cookie>();
private BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
private int maxCookies = 500;
private int sleepInterval = 200;
private string[] colors = Enum.GetNames(typeof(KnownColor));

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.progressBar1.Maximum = this.maxCookies;
    this.CenterToScreen();

    this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
    this.bgw.DoWork += delegate (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bg = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCookies; i++)
        {
            Random r = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
            Color tempColor = Color.FromName(colors[r.Next(colors.Length - 1)]);
            //StartDraw z WebService
            this.list.Add(new Cookie((ps.StartDraw(ClientRectangle.X, ClientRectangle.Y, ClientRectangle.Width, 
                ClientRectangle.Height-100)),tempColor,r.Next(360)));
            Thread.Sleep(this.sleepInterval);
            this.Invalidate();
            bg.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    };

    this.bgw.ProgressChanged += delegate (object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
      { this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; };

    this.bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
      {
          this.progressBar1.Visible=false;
          MessageBox.Show("Metoda serwisowa z osobnego wątku zakończona!");
      };
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    foreach(Cookie wp in list.ToArray())
    {
        if(wp != null)
        {
            g.FillPie(new SolidBrush(wp.Color), wp.Point.X, wp.Point.Y, 20, 20,
               wp.Angle, 280);
        }
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.textBox1.Text != null)
    {
        int interval=-1;
        int.TryParse(this.textBox1.Text, out interval);
        if(interval>0)
        {
            this.sleepInterval = interval;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Błędna liczba!");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the thing is, when I run the app and click the `button1` it all goes right until I minimize the window. After reopen it, application crushes with a null refference exception. In debugger I've checked that it is the `wp.Point.X` and `wp.Point.Y` that cause the error.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Using ClientRectangle in a worker thread is quite wrong and the reason your code fails.  Just never use a thread when it executes code that takes less than a microsecond or depends on UI or needs Thread.Sleep().  Use a Timer here.  Check WindowState in the Tick event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to allow `null` as a valid value for `Point` objects.  So, you need to check for `null` before using the `Point` property of your `Cookie` class.

```
    if(wp != null && wp.Point != null)
    {
        g.FillPie(new SolidBrush(wp.Color), wp.Point.X, wp.Point.Y, 20, 20,
           wp.Angle, 280);
    }
```

Try that.

Comment: `System.Drawing.Point` is a `struct`, so it cannot be `null`.

Comment: @Lorek thanks, it works. But I am very interested in fact why is that happening after minimizing? I mean why after reopen it becomes null?

Comment: @Dmitry It `can` be null, cause it's `Nullable<Point>`.

Comment: When minimized I suspect the `ClientRectangle` becomes `[0,0,0,0]`. You subtract 100 from the height, which means you are passing `-100` to `Random.Next(int)`.  That is probably where the exception occurs, because Next expects a positive integer.

Comment: @PawełPoręba Wrong. `wp.Point` cannot be `null` since it is declared in the `Cookie` class as `public Point Point{get; set;}`. Do you have a typo in the question?

Comment: @Dmitry, maybe this isn't a `System.Drawing.Point`.  Maybe he built his own `Point` class.  I don't see anywhere in his example that he specifies `System.Drawing.Point`.  However, if this is a `System.Drawing.Point`, which is a struct, then he should test the `wp.Point` against `System.Drawing.Point.Empty`.

Comment: @Dmitry Lorek is right. This is not `System.Drawing.Point`, it's `WinFormsConsumer.localhost.Point` which is declared as `<Nullable>Point` (see my `StartDraw()` method). This is because my task was to use `ASMX` Web Service and it doesn't support reusing types, so I'm working with proxy object (I can't convert it to `System.Drawing.Point`).